# Unresolved linker error with extern'ed global variable in multiple source files

Tags: c++, extern

I have an unresolved external symbol error that I can't seem to find the source off.
I am trying to give global access to an Engine class by declaring an instance of Engine to have external linkage (`g_engine`). My main.cpp file is the only file that defines this instance (as far as I have been able to find out). And that works fine. But when I add a call to a method on `g_engine` in another source file I get a linker error.

engine.hpp:

```
#include <other_stuff>
#include "Map.hpp"

class Engine
{
public:
  std::shared_ptr<Map> map;
  void run();
  void do_stuff();
  // other methods
};

extern Engine g_engine;  // Declared in header file
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "engine.hpp"

Engine g_engine;  // Defined only here

int main()
{
  g_engine.run();
  return 0;
}
```

map.hpp:

```
// Only includes standard headers

class Map
{
  void some_func();
}
```

**EDIT**: added comment to the constructor

map.cpp:

```
#include "engine.hpp"

Map::Map()
{
  // Calls some_func somewhere.
}

void Map::some_func()
{
  // g_engine.do_stuff()  <--- Uncommenting this line causes a linker error.
}
```

**EDIT: Added Engine.cpp**

Engine.cpp:

```
Engine::Engine()
{
  map = std::make_shared<Map>();
}

void Engine::run()
{
  // unrelated code
}
```

With the line commented out, no error is given and the application runs fine. When the line is uncommented, compiling is fine, but a linker error is given:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Engine g_engine" (?g_engine@@3VEngine@1@A) map.obj.
```

Comment: Looks like it should be ok. Are you certain your compiles are all up to date (especially main.cpp)?

Comment: How does `Engine.cpp` look?

Comment: Have you tried moving extern Engine g_engine before #include "Map.hpp"?

Comment: @LokeshRavindranathan: I presume you mean `#include "engine.hpp"`. Why do you think that would be necessary?

Comment: @LokeshRavindranathan: Not sure what adding engine.hpp to map.hpp would do other than increase compile time for files including map.hpp. Could you explain?

Comment: @arghbleargh: I have tried moving the include declaration to the implementation file and forward declared the map class, but no luck.

Comment: @Beta Most of the file does unrelated stuff, only the constructor calls some_func somewhere down a call chain. Would it help if I posted the complete code (it's rather larger than it should be)?

Comment: @FredLarson: Sorry, missed your comment. Yes, I've done a complete clean solution and rebuild solution (working with VS2012). The problem persists.

Comment: You should probably narrow it down to a complete minimal example that exhibits the behaviour. Maybe you'll find the issue yourself in the process - and if not I'm sure someone here will.

Comment: @FredLarson: I thought the header file required. After I looked again, it didn't make sense. Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When undecorated, `?g_engine@@3VEngine@1@A` is `class Engine::Engine g_engine`. Are you missing a namespace somewhere?

Comment: Yes, everything except main() is wrapped up in a namespace. Does that change things?

Comment: You seem to use namespaces wrong. You should never #include inside a namespace. You should put your own code in header and cpp inside a namespace. So your files will look as #include #include #include namespace XXX {everything else}

Comment: After you've straightened this out, the problem will very likely go away.

Comment: I don't have any includes in my namespace. I did however have my `extern Engine g_Engine` wrapped up in the namespace, when I moved it outside of the namespace the problem was resolved. The real problem was that the actual definition of `g_Engine` was in main.cpp outside of the namespace, so I instead wrapped it up inside the namespace and all was well again... Perhaps an argument to put the definition of a global variable in the implementation file of the object?

Comment: The typical use is: put "extern Engine g_engine" in header, put "Engine g_engine" in corresponding cpp. I'd rather not create a global variable at all if I were you.